# DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG - With new GPU but only on a specific System

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, cpu, gpu, directx

So, I got a GTX1080ti from eBay recently as an upgrade for my 1060. I installed it, aswell as the drivers, loaded into Apex Legends and after ~2min the screen froze and I had to quit through the Taskmanager.

**What I found out** 
In some other Games I got stuck aswell, like in Overwatch and CSGO after a few minutes (those Games through the DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG error). Some othere Games, Arma III for example, worked just fine.

**What I tried** 
I ran Furmark 1080p for about 10min and nothing happened, the GPU Temp was about 70-75°C. Than I tried CSGO on an completely other System and it did well... 
My thoughts are that something other is incompatible of some kind. Later this week I try some similar specs from a friends PC.

**My Question now is**, does anyone have an Idea what it can be? I tried resead RAM and GPU, flashed the BIOS, reinstalled DX12 and tried a fresh Win10 install.

From what I red of similar cases, the only thing left I can think of is that my Intel Turbo Boost is causing the troubles but I could not manage to disable it in the BIOS, my CPU clock is stuck by 4008.xx MHz according CPU-Z and MSI Afterburner.

**SYSTEM**

- I7-6700K @4.0GHz (stuck on 4.2 Boost), Corsair H110i AIO for cooling
- Asus Maximus VIII Ranger
- GTX 1080 ti
- 2x8GB Corsait Vengance LPX 3000MHz RAM
- RM750x (750W PowerSupply)
- Win10Pro on NVMe SSD + HDDs

Greetings!

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem.  Since the only hardware that has changed is the GPU, I would be suspicious of the GPU you purchased, I would contact the seller and ask for a refund.  Ebay offers buyer's protection for this reason.

Comment: yes, but I was suspicios cause it's only on my Main setup :I

Comment: Intel Boost is not the cause of your issues.  If Intel Boost caused problems with Nvidia graphic cards Intel would go out of business overnight.